# How to animate horizontal scroll html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw online that you could use the code at the bottom to animate a horizontal link (fiddle demo at the bottom). I am somewhat of a beginner to html, and would like to use this in the context of having an a link such as the following:

```
<a href="#nav">click this link</a>

<a name="nav" class="testing">anchor</a>
```

animate the webpage scrolling horizontally to the anchor. Here is the code with which I would like to do this:

```
function goToByScrollHoriz(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollLeft: $("#"+id).offset().left
    },'slow');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qS2Ke/1/

can anybody walk me through how?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, but I'm so lost i don't even know how to describe it. I've pretty much tried replacing the "id" in the original code with "nav", then tried creating another tag and surrounding both links with divs, but none of that has done anything

Comment: @Blaine This is a simple approach of how you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/qS2Ke/22/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need  anchor elements like

```
<a href="#d1"> d1 </a>
```

and target elements like

```
<div class="placeholder" id="d1">
```

than using this jquery

```
function horizAnim(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $(this.hash).offset().left
  }, 'slow');
}

$("a").on("click", horizAnim);
```

[this is what you get.](http://jsfiddle.net/tcpd1Lm8/1/)

Comment: and I presume the jquery goes in the <head> tag withing <script> tags?

Comment: @Blaine no, jQuery goes before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: oh, that's probably been my problem all along. so something like this?? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zRLpLB14PdoANwbhFEWpQZynp7ilVAEcKsoVlmnBM-s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @blaine you forgot to include the jQuery library.

Comment: no wonder my code is falling apart. How does one "include the jQuery library"

Comment: WOAH. got it to work somehow. Thank you for the help. I shall now go to bed, as I have wasted the past 4 hours on this darned thing.

Comment: darn it, for some reason, this makes the page scroll all the way to the end, not just to the div

Comment: if you don't want the DIVs to be 100% width, than scrollLeft might not be your best approach.

Comment: I would like each div to be 100% of the screen, but mutliple sections

Comment: oh, well, this works. It's just that it places the content at the beginning of the screen