# scrollLeft animation - clean vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, overflow

I have a question , there is possible to add animation to scrollLeft in clean vanilla JS ?

I added container with overflow:scroll and after click scrollLeft is scrolling + 100, but with no animation :(

To test it please wrap window to mobile view.

Here is the link to my codepen:

```
**https://codepen.io/pawel_wojkiewicz/pen/YzyBQvj**
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828396/how-to-animate-horizontal-scroll-html does this asnwer your query?

Comment: this is jquery not clean vanillaJS

Answer (score 23):

[Element.scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) has a `behavior` option which can be set to `smooth`

```js
document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.scroll({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    })
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 20px;
}

.box .text {
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span class="text">this textbox scrolls to the left smoothly when clicked.</span></div>
```

Comment: Julian it's very good resolve but it's impossible here to make += to the left property, only you can give hardcoded value like 0. I found resolve , CSS property to the container scroll-behavior: smooth; make it smooth :) but unfortunatelly it doesn't work on Safari and IE :(

Comment: @PawełWojkiewicz There is a polyfill to make it work on IE and Safari. Just load [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll/master/src/smoothscroll.js) before the rest of the JS gets executed.

Comment: @PawełWojkiewicz the options `left` and `top` don't need to be hardcoded. I.e. if you want to scroll the whole window to a specific element in the DOM, you can do so by setting `top: document.querySelector('.targetElement').offsetTop`

Comment: @Melchia, there's a polyfill for that. See comment above.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **scrollBy** together with **smooth** behavior:

```js
document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.scrollBy({
        left: 100,
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    })
});
```